# Got response of 409 unknown error when requesting for Uber real ride with surge confirmation

Tags: ios, uber-api

I was making request for real ride in a peak time and there was surge multiplier greater than 1 so according to Uber endpoint would return 409 code with surge confirmation info to me and then I could open a href for user to agree or deny the surge confirmation.

What I got was actually 409 code but the data was not surge confirmation but "unknown error".[image]

Please notice when there is no surge situation (meaning the surge multiplier is 1), I can successfully make a request and get a car; only when there is surge confirmation, the returned response would be like the screen shot above.

I checked Uber API doc but it didn't give much information. (409    error   - An unknown error has occurred.)

So guys please help identify this kind of error, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I tested it again with the same code, nothing changed. Now it is working fine. I am able to get a href to see the surge confirmation page and all other stuff.
So I think the issue was at Uber's side before and hopefully they can make it more stable.